# Draw a vertical line in Core Plot?

Tags: core-plot

I have an iPhone project that displays some data of the past 24h in Core Plot. x axis shows the time, y axis the data value.
Now I want to highlight a day change by drawing a vertical line at midnight. How can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a scatter plot to your graph to draw the vertical line. Just give it two data points—one for each end of the line.

Comment: This works well if the graph only contains one day change (as in the original question). But if there are two or more day changes in the same graph, a line will be drawn diagonally from the first daychange to the next. Any idea how to solve this? Is adding separate plots for each potential daychange the only way? (Seems kind of overkill)

Comment: You can insert `NAN`, `nil`, and/or `NSNull` values in the data to break the line.

Comment: Are you saying to add 3 points, say (1, 0), (1, 6), (NAN, NAN) ? And then you could add (6, 0) and (6, 6), and you would get a vertical line at x=1 and x=6?

Comment: @DavidNelson Exactly. You would have five data points, two for each of the two lines and a NAN in the middle to separate them.